# How to index column names from one df to another df series?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I have 2 data frames, 1 with raw data (df) and the other with a template describing what's in which well. How to index column names 'A1' from df with templates column well_id 'A1' which is in series, to get to the sample name?

This is how raw data is exported, so I'm trying not to make it without changing the input.

The ultimate goal is to when plotting df data to use the template "Name" for a specific sample.

My example now shows that I'm using the whole "Name" column (which is wrong) instead of just the correct name for each sample.

```
import pandas as pd
import re
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

df = pd.DataFrame({'time': [0.1, 0.2, 0.3], 
                    'A1': [1000, 2000, 3000], 
                    'A12': [1500, 2000, 3000], 
                    'B1': [4500, 5000, 6000], 
                    'B12': [4000, 5000, 6000]})

template = pd.DataFrame({'well_id': ['A1', 'A12', 'B1', 'B12'],
                         'name': ['Sample1', 'Sample2', 'Sample3', 'Sample4']})

plt.plot(df.time, df.iloc[:,1:], label=template['name']) 
plt.legend()
```

So I isolated the well_id from df, but not sure how to now marry them with the template.

```
well_id = list(filter(re.compile('[A-H][1-9]$|[A-H][1][0-2]$').match, df.columns))
```

Comment: what is the expected output?

Comment: Great question, I use data in df to plot graphs so whatever would allow me to visualize name of the sample or group by name would work for me. Like I don't know how to translate that A1 from df == A1 from the template.

Comment: `pd.merge(template, df.T, how='left', left_on='Well_id', right_index=True)` what you're after?

Comment: If there would be "well_id" in df, I think that would work, but there is none.

Comment: If you can show the output df the way you showed us the inputs, that would help. English is not my first language, so I understand data more clearly than explanations.

Comment: Mine neither. So I added my preferred output which is just a graph using df data with labels using template df. I just can't figure out how-to for all the samples to get to the correct label based on "A1, A12 etc" which overlaps among both dataframes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say, you wish to aggregate all the sample names against each of the given values, you can first merge the dataframes and then do a `groupby` on `name`. Using this, you can calculate, for example, the mean against each name like this, which can be used to further plot it:

```
import pandas as pd
import re
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

df = pd.DataFrame({'time': [0.1, 0.2, 0.3], 
                    'A1': [1000, 2000, 3000], 
                    'A12': [1500, 2000, 3000], 
                    'B1': [4500, 5000, 6000], 
                    'B12': [4000, 5000, 6000]})

template = pd.DataFrame({'well_id': ['A1', 'A12', 'B1', 'B12'],
                         'name': ['Sample1', 'Sample2', 'Sample3', 'Sample4']})

df1 = pd.merge(template, df.T, how='left', left_on='well_id', right_index=True)
df1.columns = ['well_id', 'name', 'val_1', 'val_2', 'val_3']
print(df1.head())
```

Output of `df1.head()` looks like this:

```
  well_id     name   val_1   val_2   val_3
0      A1  Sample1  1000.0  2000.0  3000.0
1     A12  Sample2  1500.0  2000.0  3000.0
2      B1  Sample3  4500.0  5000.0  6000.0
3     B12  Sample4  4000.0  5000.0  6000.0
```

Once you have `df1`, you can aggregate the data and plot it like this:

```
df1.groupby('name').mean().plot.line()
plt.title("Values Grouped on Sample Names", size=20)
plt.show()
```

[image: Plot of Values Grouped on Sample Names]

Comment: Thank you! I can't believe I was just looking for a transpose function, now it seems so obvious. I went into the direction of pivot tables and multi indexing, that just became too overwhelming too fast.